# Exporting a group of raster layer bounds from QGIS to a GeoJSON

Tags: qgis, raster, polygon, geojson, mapbox

I have a QGIS project with a lot of raster layers; and I want to build a [Mapbox map](https://www.mapbox.com/) based on this project; that would display those images on a website's map.

[image]

I need a way to **export a group of raster layers** from QGIS to a **GeoJSON collection** of polygons; that I could load in Mapbox.

I already had a look on GeoTIFF files and PGW files; but still, exporting every layer one by one will be painful - as I'll have to update the web project from QGIS quite often.

So I'm looking for a solution that would automate the job.

I would like to get a GeoJSON file that would look like this:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "layer_name": "AND17",
        "image": "images/png/world.png",
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              4.3813338557822,
              50.842573058675
            ],
            [
              4.418685805334,
              50.842573058675
            ],
            [
              4.418685805334,
              50.825893099756
            ],
            [
              4.3813338557822,
              50.825893099756
            ],
            [
              4.3813338557822,
              50.842573058675
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

As you can see, it contains the georeferencing informations of the image, and its filename.
If I can get that, i'm able to load and place the image on Mapbox.

Have you got any ideas of how I could do that; maybe using a plugin?

I've also seen that you can export a group to a *.qlr file.
It seems that it contains some kind of geospatial datas :

```
<extent>
    <xmin>475442.96307834662729874</xmin>
    <ymin>6588302.91859502345323563</ymin>
    <xmax>483907.46308698022039607</xmax>
    <ymax>6594287.91860113199800253</ymax>
</extent>
```

Any tips ?

Answer (score 1):

This script is assuming you want to save the bounds of all the raster layers.

```
import json

layers = [layer for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values() if layer.type() == QgsMapLayerType.RasterLayer]
gj = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features":[]
  }
for layer in layers:
    extent = layer.extent()
    feature = {
        "type": "Feature",
          "properties": {
            "layer_name": layer.name(),
            "image": layer.source(),
            },
              "geometry": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [
                  [
                    [
                      extent.xMinimum(),
                      extent.yMinimum()
                    ],
                    [
                      extent.xMaximum(),
                      extent.yMinimum()
                    ],
                    [
                      extent.xMaximum(),
                      extent.yMaximum()
                    ],
                    [
                      extent.xMinimum(),
                      extent.yMaximum()
                    ],
                    [
                      extent.xMinimum(),
                      extent.yMinimum()
                    ]
                  ]
                ]
              }
            }
    gj['features'].append(feature)
    
    output_dir = r'C:\Work'
    with open('{}/image_bounds.geojson'.format(output_dir), 'w') as file: # Change the location
        file.write(json.dumps(gj))
```